# CSS Flex all center except single right horizontally aligned element

Tags: css, flexbox

Using CSS flex I'm trying to get all inline elements centered *except* one inline element to align on the right. I do not want to extend the size of the boxes or change anything in regards to their vertical axis. I've not been able to get any further than what this [CSS Flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=center&align-items=flex-start&align-content=flex-start&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) can produce on it's own. If I add `margin-left` on the last element then all the other elements align to the left. After that point if I add `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` to all of the other elements they spread out. The fact that the distinction between horizontal and vertical *does not help*.

How do I keep the first three elements to remain grouped and centered and only change the horizontal layout of the last element to be aligned to the right? I would prefer to be able to still use `margin-right: 2px;` to not have it immediantly up against the border of `.parentNode.parentNode`

```
<header>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
<span>Item 4</span>
</header>
```

A visual demonstration of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: CSS Flex all horizontally centered except one element aligned right]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
<span>Item 4</span>
</header>
```

Comment: There will be overlapping if absolute is used here